# how to call javascript function from c# in razor v2

Tags: asp.net, web, webforms, razor-2

I have javascript function which creates a notification by using noty javascript plugin,

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function generateAnoty(message) {
        var noty_id = noty({
            layout: 'center',
            text: message,
            modal: true,
            type: 'success',
        });
    }
    </script>
```

I'm using razor v2 as view engine with C# and web forms frame work not mvc.
After submitting the form I would like to call the javascript function above.
Here is an example of what I'm trying to do;

```
   //place for c#
   if (IsPost)
   {
       //after submitting the form
       //I wanna somehow call the js to show noty message
       generateAnoty("You have successfully submitted the form!")
   }
```

p.s. if I try to call generateAnoty(message) js method by using any html button onclick eventhandler it work well.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you are submitting your form you could do this..

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Results", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId="Results", OnBegin="ShowLoading", OnComplete="generateAnoty", OnFailure="Error" }))
{
   // Code here
}
```

note: you'll have to replace the name of certain things depending on what you have on your form. In this example I have a function that Shows a loading image OnBegin and OnComplete you can have it go away, or show the message, whatever you want. Just replace what you need and it should work out.

Answer (score 0):

To add script that will run after postback in your frame you can use either [ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310408%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) or [Page.ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy.aspx) methods.

Use `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` if your web form inside frame uses UpdatePanel otherwise use `Page.ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` method.

As sort of unified solution for RegisterStartupScript you can use following extension method:

```
public static void RegisterStartupScript(this Page page, string scriptText)
{
    var scriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(page);
    if (scriptManager != null && scriptManager.IsInAsyncPostBack)
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, page.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), scriptText, true);
    else
        page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(page.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), scriptText, true);
}
```

Comment: Page.ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript is the part of System.Web.UI.Page class however my Page object derived from WebPageBase.Page since I'm using Razor view engine. So when I try to use your method I'm getting this error:
The best overloaded method match for  'WebUtils.RegisterStartupScript(System.Web.UI.Page, string)' has some invalid arguments.

When I try to cast my Page object in razor then I get this error:
Cannot convert type 'System.Dynamic.DynamicObject' to 'System.Web.UI.Page'

So, I'm wondering if there is a way to use RegisterStartupScript method in Razor view engine.

Comment: @bilmuhfk You were writing "I'm using razor v2 as view engine with C# and web forms frame work not mvc". I understood this that you have a frame tag which points to .aspx page and you want to execute script after .aspx page processes the postback. If this is not the case my answer have nothing with you problem.

Comment: I have .cshtml pages not the ones with .aspx So as you said my case is different. But thanks for your reply anyway.